# Plugin for org chart in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, orgchart

I'm looking for a react plugin to display an organization chart based on the JSON data that I pass to it in my React application. I need basic functionality like if a user clicks on an employee in org chart, I get back data about that employee in return. Like this[image]

Answer (score 4):

The best plugin that I came across till now is this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/orgchart

It contains enough features and customizability. Kudos to the team that has developed it. Looking forward to contributing towards this and request other also to do the same.